# Checkbox making textbox mandatory

Tags: php, function

This may a bit hard to explain and i may not explain it properly (i haven't slept) and if so i am sorry i will try make it as easy as possible to understand. I currently have a checkbox (select) and a text box (attend) which are disabled and one checkbox that is not disabled(enable2), i have a function above my form HTML which works on the "enable2" checkbox so that once it is checked it enables the checkbox "select". What i was wondering how to do is once the "select" checkbox is enabled and you then check that box can it then enable the text box "attend" and also make that field mandatory as well? Here is my current code :

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {

document.getElementById('enable2').onchange=function(){

    var d = document.getElementById('box').childNodes;
    for( i=0, l=d.length; i<l; i++ )
    {
        d[i].disabled = !this.checked;
    }
};
}
</script>

<form name="eoiform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi" onsubmit="return  ">

Enable Section D
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="enable2" id="enable2">

<div id="box">
<b><p>Section D - Academically selective school</b></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="select" id="select" disabled />
<p>I have submitted an application for placement in an academically selective school. My child will be sitting for the Selective High Schools test. In case your child is not successful in gaining a place in this/these school(s), please also complete Section B,  Section C or Section E on this form.</p>
</div>

<div id="txts2">
<b><p>Section E - Placement not required</b></p>
<p>I will not be seeking to enrol my child in a NSW government school next year. My child will be attending the following school in 2015:*</p>
<input type="text" id="attend" name="attend" disabled />
<br>
<br>
Parent/Carer <input type="text" id="parentd" name="parentd" disabled />
<br>
Date <input type="text" id="datee" name="datee" disabled />
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<script>
function validateCheckBoxes(theForm) {
if (!theForm.declare.checked) {
    alert ('You must tick the checkbox to confirm the declaration');
    return false;
} else {    
    return true;
}
}

var form = document.getElementById('eoi'),
validNumbers = [2474,
                2750,
                2753,
                2760,
                2777];

form.onsubmit = function() {

var userInput = document.getElementById("post"),
    numb = parseInt(userInput.value, 10);
if ( validNumbers.indexOf(numb) == -1 ) {
    alert("Please enter a correct postcode");
    return false;
}

return validateCheckBoxes(form);

}
</script>
```

If that explanation wasn't clear once again i am sorry, just ask if you need anything clarified and any help on this would be appreciated as i am just learning javascript.

Comment: you have 2 instances of `validateCheckBoxes()`. get some sleep

Answer (score 0):

just modify your `form.onsubmit = function() {` with this, subsituting your vars and IDs and such.

```
var checkboxToMakeTextareamandatory = document.getElementByID(...);
var mandatoryTextarea= document.getElementByID(...);

if(checkboxToMakeTextareamandatory .checked && mandatoryTextarea.value == "") {
    alert(...);
}
```